# How to avoid having newlines with grep -o for multiple match at the same line (on a text of several lines)

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have the following text:

```
aaa rr tt zz pp
aaa pp xx yy uu zz
```

And need to extract all 'aaa', 'zz' and 'xx' pattern and print them on one line like this:

```
aaa zz
aaa xx zz
```

Best I found is `grep -oP 'aaa|xx|zz'` but this return each pattern found on a new line:

```
aaa
zz
aaa
xx
zz
```

I tried to add something like `tr -d '\n'` but in that case it returns the whole matches on single line which is not what I want.

NB: I need a solution which support regexp with non-greedy regexp as the search patterns would looks like: `^.+?,|,IN:.+?\-|,OUT:.+?-|State.+?[$,]`

Comment: You may be able to do this simply with: `awk -F= '{ printf "%s", $0" "}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
 while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo $(grep -oP 'aaa|xx|zz' <<< "$line");
 done < file
```

That is,

1. Read input file line by line
2. Get your matches with the `grep` command per each line
3. The shell will convert the newlines with spaces as the `$(...)` is not enclosed with double quotes.

If you have specific whitespace inside matches that you want to preserver, consider using

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
  echo "$(grep -oP 'aaa|xx|zz' <<< "$line" | awk '{ printf "%s", $0" "}')"; 
done < file
```

This way, you will get per-line matches in a space-separated way. You may use any custom delimiter in the `awk` command (after `$0`).

Comment: You don't need the Awk if you use the (then not) useless `echo`, or vice versa.

Comment: @tripleee If you could provide a variation of the command you mean it would be helpful. I tried without, but this was the only one that worked.

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo $(grep -oP 'aaa|xx|zz' <<<"$line"); done <<$'aaa bb cc\nzz xx yy\nboo baa`

Comment: Well not exactly; the *shell* will flatten whitespace when you pass an unquoted string such as the result of a command substitution. Equivalently `echo "$(grep -oP 'aaa|xx|zz' | awk '{ printf "%s", $0 }')"` would work, and properly quote the output from the shell. This is the better approach if the output from `grep` could contain irregular whitespace and/or unquoted wildcards. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: @tripleee Yes, OP sample input is too simplified

Comment: Thanks, this works very fine but it is extremely slow (when using complex regexp)

Comment: @xtruder99 That might be a problem with regex. Your `^.+?,|,IN:.+?\-|,OUT:.+?-|State.+?[$,]` is very inefficient, and I a m afraid wrong. What do you want to match with `[$,]`? Do you realize it matches `$` or `,` symbols? If you mean end of string or `,` you need `^[^,]*,|,IN:[^-]*-|,OUT:[^-]*|State[^,]*,`. Also, no need to use `P`, use `E` with this pattern, as there are no PCRE specific constructs any longer. If input text is long, lazy dot pattern may be a really dangerous pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well your argument on the pertinence of my regexp are not receivable, but anyway I have done more tests and indeed the performance are terrible on cygwin (like processing 3 lines/seconds) but not really noticeable on a native linux. So I'll accept that one :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `grep -P`, here is a simple Awk postprocessor to rearrange the output into the desired format.

```sh
grep -Pno '^.+?,|,IN:.+?\-|,OUT:.+?-|State.+?[$,]' - /dev/null <file |
awk 'BEGIN { re="^\\(standard input\\):[1-9][0-9]*:" }
    $0 ~ re { sep="\n"; sub(re, "") }
    { if(NR>1) printf "%s", sep; printf "%s", $0; sep=" " }
    END { if(sep) printf "\n" }'
```

If the `grep` results could accidentally output a prefix which looks like `(standard input):1:` from an actual match, this won't work.

This is from BSD `grep`; if your local `grep` outputs a differently formatted file name prefix for standard input (or if you need to refactor to read a number of named files instead of standard input), the Awk regex will need to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Tripleee, I tried several machine but could not make it work. However, the idea of adding the -n on grep was very good, so I made my own version:
awk -F':' '{curr = $1;
sub("^[1-9][0-9]*:", "");
if(prev && prev!=curr) {print STR; STR=$0;}
else {if (!prev) STR=$0;
   else STR=STR " " $0;}
prev=curr;}
END {print STR}'